# How to get the Android graph view?

Tags: android, graph

Actually i have try display the charts in my application already i saw graph view in **jjoe64 developer blog** but i cann't understand.Any one plz forward the the how to display the charts using graphview.

```
GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewData[] {  
      new GraphViewData(1, 2.0d)  
      , new GraphViewData(2, 1.5d)  
      , new GraphViewData(3, 2.5d)  
      , new GraphViewData(4, 1.0d)  
});  

GraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(  
      this // context  
      , "GraphViewDemo" // heading  
);  
graphView.addSeries(exampleSeries); // data  

LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);  
layout.addView(graphView);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently worked in AndroidPlot library for graphs in Android and must say its quite useful. You can check it out [here](http://androidplot.com/)

You'll find the examples there explaining how to plot a graph..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use Android Graph View library.

You should read the coding in [GraphView-Demo](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView-Demos) first of all things you will work.